# Android emulator crashing on Windows 7 64 Bit

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am a newbie android developer and so far have only got Hello World running on my android phone.

When I try to run my app in emulator mode I see the emulator window with the keyboard and answer / hangup buttons but I get a windows dialogue before my app runs sayingemulator.exe has stopped responding:

[image]

Can anyone else get the emulator to run on 64 bit Windows 7 Professional? I have a 32 bit JDK and run 32 bit Eclipse 3.5.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I do Android development on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, with a 32 bit JDK and 32 Eclipse 3.5 and have not experienced the emulator crashing. Have you tried running the emulator with one of the sample applications to ensure it's not your project that's causing the problem? Beyond that, I'd recommend googling for information on how you can submit an error log to Google.

Comment: I am running Win 7/64 and the API 15 emulator works in WVGA800 mode but not WXGA800 mode. Also crashes if 1024x800 Resolution is set. API 13 works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Emulator runs just fine for me on 64 bit Windows 7. But I have seen emulator crashing when trying to debug. I could start it on it's own, but when I tried to run it from eclipse it crashed. Try this:

1. Close eclipse and kill adb process
2. Delete your virtual device and create a new one

Comment: Thanks for the post. It seems that I just had to delete the device and create a new one. I don't know what I did wrong in the first place.

Comment: Awesome.. just in time to save my day! Almost after an year and still the same problem exists!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you and realised that it was the firewal that was blocking it. So I went to the program exe, `right click -> properties and in compatibility click on run as administrator`. Then try running the program and you will get a firewall promt asking if you want to the give the program access, choose yes and sorted. You should have the AVD working now.

Answer (score 0):

I was running 64-bit ADT with 64-bit Windows 7 and 64-bit Java. First time I ran the ADT, adb crashed. I then re-ran ADT using Run As Administrator, and adb did not crash.