# Starting AVD Emulator always gives "Android Emulator Closed unexpectedly"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

My sincere thanks for your reading this.

I have just installed Android Studio and am attempting to run the default `Hello World!` script that is present when you create a new project.

Every time I try to run the the program in an Android Emulator my Emulator crashes and I get the error `"Android Emulator Closed Unexpectedly"` Every. Single. Time.

I have the `Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)` installed as suggested:

[image]

I try to run a Nexus 4 emulator with 512 mb of Ram and it never works:

[image]

When I run this I get:

[image]

During this, my system physical memory peaks at 80% but never goes to 100 (which I would expect if it were crashing).

I have searched similar questions including

[Android emulator crashing on Windows 7 64 Bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167404/android-emulator-crashing-on-windows-7-64-bit) [Android 4.0 emulator always has a crashing Launcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155417/android-4-0-emulator-always-has-a-crashing-launcher) [Android studio emulator fails to start with memory limit related error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269121/android-studio-emulator-fails-to-start-with-memory-limit-related-error-message) and they say to lower the memory size (which is what I am trying to do). Unfortunately this isn't working

Any idea how I can solve this issue?

My computer specs are as follows:
64 Bit Windows
6gb Ram
Intel Core i3

I downloaded and installed all correct versions as instructed here: https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, this issue took the whole weekend to solve.

All options I tried, until:

Android Development Studio prompted me to update the Android Emulator Version to 25.3.1 (no idea what it was on before as I didn't check this before). This was a download of ~170mb.

Once I downloaded and installed the update, the emulator now seems to run OK on low memory settings - settings in keeping with the answer to this question here: [Android emulator generates a very annoying error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381456/android-emulator-generates-a-very-annoying-error)

I am now running with settings:

> RAM memory to 5012
>
> Virtual heap 32
>
> Internal storage 200 mb
>
> External storage 64 mb

So basically, it was a complete fluke that this worked.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone that gets this error after rooting the android image, (if using snapshots). You need to start the virtual device with the `-writable-system` parameter like when you rooted the device, excerpt from [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#snapshots).

> Snapshots
>
> ...Starting a virtual device by loading a snapshot is much like waking a physical from a sleep state, as opposed to booting it from a powered-off state.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem, Every time I was starting Emulator, it was closing unexpectedly. then I tried to change the ***Emulator Performance*** in settings of AVD Managers; In Software it's not working but in Hardware it was showing blank black screen.
Then I realized, there might be some issue with Graphics Card(mine NVIDIA GeForce 940MX), It was showing this error 
[image]

After Updating/Restarting the problem was not resolving, then I Disabled then Enabled the Graphics Card Driver in the Device Manager and It worked!!

**LONG STORY SHORT**: Check, the problem might be due to your Graphics Card!

Answer (score -1):

in my case, i attempted using gennymotion [ you may install it asking google   genymotion .  com] this could serve as alternative.

if gennymotion after installation returns this error message "the version of openGl supported by your graphics card is too old:Genymotion requires at least openGl 2.0 support. "

then know our challenge is  arising from not having required graphics driver

either you checkout this link [https://buffered.com/support/solve-opengl-error/]  on how to resolve it in steps.

or you download the graphics drivers using the links below

Here are the links to the 4 most prominent graphics card manufacturers in the world:

Intel: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html

restart your systems after installation of the appropriate graphics driver and continue your project .